# How to extract columns from multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, count, frequency

Sorry for this simple question. I have a very basic R script that extracts and counts occurrences of same items under a specific column in a very large *.csv file and gives me a list of items and their frequencies like this:

```
COLUMNNAME     freq

 item1         15

 item2         7

 item3         500

and so on...
```

The script is like this:

```
library(plyr)
my_file<-read.csv(file='file1.csv', header=TRUE, sep = '')
count(my_file, vars='COLUMNNAME')
```

My question is how to do this again for my other 25 *.csv files and write the results into an output.csv file like this:

```
COLUMNNAME   file1.csv    file2.csv    ......

item1            15            ?

item2            7             ?

item3           500           ?

and so on...
```

The files are structured the same way and contain the same items but with different frequencies. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

One snapshot from my sample file in csv is like this:
[image: samplefile]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the files, e.g. using `list.files`. Then you can loop over the files, and load them, and add them to the bottom of a new `data.frame`. Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

csv.files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", recursive=TRUE)
bg.df <- NULL

for (csv.file in csv.files) {
    if (is.null(bg.df)) {
        bg.df <- readr::read_csv(csv.file) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(
        file = csv.file
      )
    } else {
    bg.df <- bg.df %>%
      dplyr::add_row(
        readr::read_csv(csv.file) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(
            file = csv.file
          )
      )
    }
}
```

Now, you can also make them wide again using `tidyr::pivot_wider`, but I am unsure about how your data looks like.

Regardless, you can use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize` to make a summary, if needed. But to write that bit, I need a some example data/files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This also worked. But it gave me a single file with all data appended with filenames in a separate column This is fine. But interestingly the whole file is turned into just two columns with \t between column names. I could not manage to split them but I am trying, fingers crossed.

Comment: @EmrahPeksoy Do you have an example of a file?

Comment: I pasted a photo on the original post above.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: I added the code from my comment.

See if this works

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# udf for collecting frequencies
tableIt <- function(tbl){
  fread(tbl) %>% 
    select(colChosen) %>%  # change colChosen to the column name you're looking for
    {table(.)}
}

# collect file names and call udf
filesToReview <- 
  list.files(path = whateverYourPathIs, 
             pattern = "*.csv", 
             full.names = T) %>%  # keep full directory
  # if you have files in subfolders, you can add recursive = T to look there, too
  set_names(str_extract(., "([^\\/]+$)")) %>%
  map(~tableIt(.))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works like a charm except a single issue which is not a big deal: It gives me a list like this:

```
item1   45      item1   76       item1  8
item2   13      item2   7         item2  140
```
and column headers are Freq, Freq1, Freq2, Freq3.........

I assume it processes the files in alphabetical order? It would be better if I had file names as headers of frequencies like:

```
ITEMS    filex    filez    fileh  
item1      45      76       8
item2      13       7       140
item3      ......................
```

Comment: Between `list.files()` and `map()`, add `set_names(str_extract(., "([^\\/]+$)"))`. That will give you the file name as the name of each table in the list. Alternatively, you can just use `set_names()` and the file name, along with the path will be the name of each table in the list.